# Kops and Spot instances with new pricing model

Tags: kubernetes

AWS introduced a [simpler pricing model](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-amazon-ec2-spot-pricing/):

> You don’t have to bid for Spot Instances in the new pricing model, and you just pay the Spot price that’s in effect for the current hour for the instances that you launch.

Does Kops support querying the current hour's Spot price and then using it? The docs I've found so far talk about the `maxPrice` option rather than a way of specifying the *current price*.